# Why does @Published attribute cause this error: Type 'Booking' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'

Tags: swift, combine, codable

I ran into a **weird problem**. Just adding the attribute **@Published** causes this error: *"Type 'Booking' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'"*

**THIS compiles fine:**

```
class Booking: ObservableObject, Codable {
    private (set) var module    : Module   
    private (set) var lecturer  : Lecturer? = nil
    
    init(withModul module : Module) {
        self.module = module
    }
}
```

**WHILE here comes the error:**

```
class Booking: ObservableObject, Codable {
    private (set) var module : Module   
    @Published private (set) var lecturer : Lecturer? = nil

    init(withModul module : Module) {
        self.module = module
    }
}
```

And of course type 'Lecturer' and 'Module' (which are structs) conform both to 'Codable' and also all its properties.

**Never had that problem before, any suggestions.**

Comment: `Published` isn't `Codable` you have to manually create the implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you've added the `@Published` property wrapper to `lecturer`, the type of that property is now `Published<Lecturer>` rather than `Lecturer`. `Published` doesn't conform to `Codable` even if it's wrapped `Value` conforms to `Codable`.

If you don't want the wrapped property to be part of the encoding/decoding, you can simply omit it from the `Codable` conformance by creating a `CodingKey` conformant enum for `Booking` and omitting the `lecturer` property from there.

```
class Booking: ObservableObject, Codable {
    private (set) var module : Module
    @Published private (set) var lecturer : Lecturer? = nil

    init(withModul module : Module) {
        self.module = module
    }

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case module
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you do want encode/decode `lecturer`, you need to manually implement the `Codable` conformance.

```
class Booking: ObservableObject, Codable {
  private (set) var module : Module
  @Published private (set) var lecturer : Lecturer? = nil

  init(withModul module : Module) {
    self.module = module
  }

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case module
    case lecturer
  }

  required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    self.lecturer = try container.decodeIfPresent(Lecturer.self, forKey: .lecturer)
    self.module = try container.decode(Module.self, forKey: .module)
  }

  func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    try lecturer?.encode(to: encoder)
    try module.encode(to: encoder)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this great answer. So Published<T> does not conform to codable, although T conforms. And I thought it has something to do with the 'optional' implementation of lecturer.